# What is a plural of "To-Do"? "To-Dos" or "To-Does"?

Tags: plural-forms, contractions

Say I have a list of "To-Do" things. I want to mention them to someone, so I doubt on how to call it:

> 1. I have many "**To-Dos**" for today
>   2. I have many "**To-Does**" for today
>   3. I have many "**To-Do's**" for today

None of them looks fine to me, but I don't know how to check it out.

Comment: Alternately, you can use "to-do" as an adjective:  "I have a long "to-do" list for today.

Comment: @Andrew Exactly my thought, except for I think I might not use *for*.

Comment: @DamkerngT.  Agreed, the "for" is optional.

Comment: "I have lots to do today"

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> In special cases, such as when forming a plural of a word that is not normally a noun, some writers add an apostrophe for clarity.
>
> Example: Here are some do's and don'ts.
>
> In that sentence, the verb do is used as a plural noun, and the apostrophe was added because the writer felt that dos was confusing. Not all writers agree; some see no problem with dos and don'ts. ([Source.](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/apostro.asp))

So I can imagine that many would say *to-do's* is ok. *to-does* doesn't seem right, though I can't explicitly exclude it.

However, according to the Free Dictionary [[1]](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/to-do) and Merriam-Webster [[2]](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/to%E2%80%93do), the plural form is

> to–dos

---

The original question asks for the plural of *to-do*, but OP's given examples might sound funny or odd. Instead, you could say "I have a long to-do list" or "I have many things on my to-do list", for starters.

<sub>Speaking of lists, you could also say "I have a [laundry list](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/laundry%20list) of things to do", though this is an aside :)</sub>

Comment: "To-does" is almost like a pun or a joke: "I had a long 'to-do' list, but I procrastinated so long it's now a 'to-does" list ..."

Comment: @Andrew "to-didn'ts" would fit better in the punchline IMO

Comment: @QPaysTaxes yeah now that I re-read it, I'm glad I don't work in comedy  :)

Comment: @Andrew well, that was bad :D I would almost read "to-does" as the third person of the verb "do", so it would be like a "to-do" that someone else does.

Answer (score 7):

I wouldn't use the second one, since the second part looks like "many female deer (does)", or simply the English word "does" as in "he does the dishes".

And I dislike seeing apostrophes to indicate plurals - but they are accepted in rare circumstances.

That only leaves the first one: "To-Dos".

Comment: +1'd Thank you for showing how to capitalize that word, to-dos => To-Dos.

Answer (score 1):

I would skip all of that and just say "I have a lot to do today" or "I have a lot on my to-do list".

[Google NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+-+dos%2Cto+-+do%27s%2Cto+-+do+list%2Cto+-+does&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20--%20dos%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20--%20do%20list%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20--%20does%3B%2Cc0) shows "to-do list" beating the other options by a wide margin.  If you really want to go with one of them, to-dos is the most common, then to-do's, with to-does being dead last.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Fixed the link

Comment: Hi, perhaps narrowing down the search from 1970 is more relevant https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to-dos%2Cto-do%27s%2Cto-do+list%2Cto+-+does&year_start=1970&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20-%20dos%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20-%20do%20%27s%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20-%20do%20list%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20--%20does%3B%2Cc0, i

Answer (score 1):

A distinction should be made between many items on a single to-do list or many to-do lists.   Additionally, to-do is the adjective describing the type of list.   The noun "list" is often understood and omitted.

If you want to pluralise or emphasize the number of tasks then I would suggest something like:

1. *I have many tasks (or items) on my to-do list today*. (more formal), or
2. *I have a long to-do list today*.  (more informal and the noun "list" is still typically used)

but for numerous lists, I would say:

3. *I have a several to-do lists to complete today*.

... and for a maximized workload of many tasks on many lists:

4. *I have a lot of tasks on my to-do lists today*.

Answer (score 0):

The plural of To-Do is **To-Dos**. So the correct usage would be

> I have many To-Dos for today

Comment: Welcome to ELL. You should include your reasoning or justification for your answer, otherwise it's just your opinion. A dictionary entry, examples of real-world usage, or statistics would make this a good answer.